# Unwanted behavior onBackPressed during onRefresh by SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I got one child activity with a SwipeRefreshLayout. 
When using the back button (calls onBackpressed()), I expect the activity to finish and open the parent activity.

**Expected:**
When I use swipe to refresh and let the application load for a while (took away real networking, so the loading process takes longer), then press back button so onBackPressed is called, everything works as expected.
The child-activity closes and parent-activity opens.
This is the normal behavior.

**Questionable Behavior:**
When I do the same, but press the back button fast, shortly after activating the refresh by one down-swipe, the loading animation stops and the complete view dissapears and seems to get recreated.

**My Questions:**
Has anyone had the same problem? Is this normal?
Am I understanding something wrong?

[image: Example Image of Behavior]

The Child-Activity:

```
public class ContactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@BindView(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;
@BindView(R.id.contacts_swipe_container) SwipeRefreshLayout refreshContainer;
@BindView(R.id.contacts_recycler_view) RecyclerView recyclerView;

private ContactsRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    refreshContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            //commented so the refresh process holds on
            //fetchUpdates(0);
        }
    });
    // Configure the refreshing colors
    refreshContainer.setColorSchemeResources(
            android.R.color.holo_blue_light,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);

    // Set the adapter
    adapter = new ContactsRecyclerViewAdapter(contacts);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.devte.eventr.controller.contacts.ContactsActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/contacts_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And the included XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_contacts"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.devte.eventr.controller.contacts.ContactsActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/contacts">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/contacts_swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/contacts_item"
            android:id="@+id/contacts_recycler_view"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think you need to handle when pressing back button what happen ?

Comment: What do you mean? I explained both results in my question. The expected the unexpected behavior after pressing the back button.

Comment: I mean you want another thing to happen when you press back button so you need a method that you says in it what to happen, true that's what you need? or i misunderstand ?

Comment: I just want the "normal" behavior. Is it normal, that the view recreates, if I immediately use the back button while the SwipeRefreshLayout loads? I guess not, so what leads to this behavior? Thats the main question.

Comment: okey I got it but will you add your onBackpressed method

Comment: The thing is, there is nothing implemented. I dont override it.